# Updating packages on CentOS via dnf module list using https?

Tags: centos, dnf

I have a new Centos 8 installation and am trying to use dnf to install the packages I need. Company rules (and common sense, honestly) is that any outgoing traffic needs to be done over HTTPS. However running this command:

dnf module list

fails because it is trying to connect to http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?...

Is there any way to get dnf to use https instead?

Comment: In `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`, is the `mirrorlist` setting explicitly set to http? Can this be changed to https? Question was also asked [here](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=76180).

Comment: Looking at the URL, there doesn't seem to be an https version at least for this repository.

Comment: CentOS 8 had **End Of Life** 'Jan 31 - 2021': No more updates. Links to repo's were changed to "the Vault"  https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/ ...... Example edited repo files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cqafM9dnGZNgUBm5ozKNR9EhOkFbLLEs?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[CentOS Linux 8 had reached the End Of Life (EOL)](https://techglimpse.com/failed-metadata-repo-appstream-centos-8/) on December 31st, 2021. It means that CentOS 8 will no longer receive development resources from the official CentOS project. After Dec 31st, 2021, if you need to update your CentOS, you need to change the mirrors to vault.centos.org where they will be archived permanently.

Run the below commands

```
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Now you are good to go ahead and update packages

```
# dnf update -y
```

Comment: Hello Santhosh, and welcome to U&L! If you are the same person who authored the article that you've linked to, you need to [disclose that affiliation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) so that you're not seen as spamming the link. Happily, the rest of your post appears to address the question, so I wanted to address the affiliation requirement of Stack Exchange with you. Thank you for your attention!